# Rdlc report not showing data on web page

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
string sql = "select Prg_Name, Goal, Domain,Step_Desc_Oreginal FROM dbo.TBL_CTL_ControlProgram  where PRG_ID = " + prg_id;
DataSet ds = db.GetDS(sql, "CIBCTL");
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Step_Desc_Oreginal", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Prg_Name", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Domain", typeof(string)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Goal", typeof(string)));

        ///////////////////


        //////////////////
foreach (DataRow ProgRow in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    dt.Rows.Add(ProgRow["Step_Desc_Oreginal"].ToString(), ProgRow["Prg_Name"].ToString(), ProgRow["Domain"].ToString(), ProgRow["Goal"].ToString());
}
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
ReportViewer1.Reset();
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
//ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath(@"CIB_CTL\\ReportProg.rdlc"); //"CIB_CTL\\ReportProg.rdlc";

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "ReportProg.rdlc";  //"CIB_CTL\\ReportProg.rdlc";//Server.MapPath(@"ReportProg.rdlc");

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();






<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server"  Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt"  WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt" Width="950px" Height="550px" AsyncRendering="False">
    <ServerReport ReportServerUrl="" />
    <LocalReport ReportPath="ReportProg.rdlc">
        <DataSources>
            <rsweb:ReportDataSource DataSourceId="ObjectDataSource1" Name="DataSet1" />
        </DataSources>
    </LocalReport>
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"  SelectMethod="GetData" TypeName="CIBPRJ.CIB_CTL.ProgDataSetTableAdapters.DataTable1TableAdapter"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Comment: can anybody help me in resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no need to mention all the dataset information in aspx and in also code behind . You just entered all necessary codes in aspx . In it exclude this line .

```
 <ServerReport ReportServerUrl="" />
```

Its not necessary . You have specified `SelectMethod="GetData"` in the markup but I cant see any GetData method in the backend that returns any data item that match Dataset1 .
So it will works if you remove those lines

```
ReportViewer1.ProcessingMode = ProcessingMode.Local;
ReportViewer1.Reset();
ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", dt);
//ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = Server.MapPath(@"CIB_CTL\\ReportProg.rdlc"); //"CIB_CTL\\ReportProg.rdlc";

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = "ReportProg.rdlc";  //"CIB_CTL\\ReportProg.rdlc";//Server.MapPath(@"ReportProg.rdlc");

ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
```

and define the GetData properly .

Comment: thanks for your answer. but i am getting the data in dataset and getdata() is defined in dataset creation. problem is that report is shown with disabled header and no data in report. i have checked the code its working fine. i think i am missing some property or configuration of report.